# publishing a flash project in html, fullscreen code preventing animation

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash

Hello I'm making a flash interactive CD and my clients needs a mac, pc and linux version, for linux he asked me to make a html with the flash inside. PC and mac are running perfectly however when I export into the html my flash timeline gets stuck at frame1 and the little animation I made to zoom to the main screen is not loading.

After some testing I realized that my very first code line is somehow doing this:

```
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;

stage.scaleMode =StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL;
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```

This is the code I use to force fullscreen in mac and pc but it makes the html one stuck on frame 1, if I delete that code the html version runs fine, what is it?

Working on Flash cs6, as3, for flash player 9 (tried up to 11.2 and not working either)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your animation probably doesn't work because there is an error while executing in browser.

The security restriction for StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN in flash player is different from the AIR desktop application.

> In Flash Player, full-screen mode can only be initiated through ActionScript in response to a mouse click (including right-click) or keypress. AIR content running in the application security sandbox does not require that full-screen mode be entered in response to a user gesture.

[Adobe documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e31.html#WS2E9C7F3B-6A7C-4c5d-8ADD-5B23446FBEEB)

Also check if you use the tag in HTML while embedding. That is allowing web content to become fullscreen.

```
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer I tried different things and everything pointed to the code I wrote before, the curious thing is I tried the AS2 version of that code and it works perfectly. I ended up moving the code the end of the animaiton 10 frames later so it takes half a second for desktop user to get into fullscreen but at least is working on html now.